# Sum of everything inside a list

Tags: python, regex

I am extracting numbers from sentences within a large file. Example sentence (in file `finalsum.txt`):

```
the cat in the 42 hat and the cow 1772 jumps over the moon.
```

I then use regular expressions to create a list where I want to add together 1772 + 42 for the entire file creating a final sum of all the numbers.

Here is my current code :

```
import re
import string
fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')

try:
    if len(fname) < 1: fname = "finalsum.txt"
    handle = open(fname, 'r')
except:
    print 'Cannot open file:', fname

counts = dict()
numlist = list()
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('([0-9]+)', line)
    if len(x) > 0:
        result = map(int, x)
        numlist.append(result)
        print numlist
```

I know this code can be written in two lines using line comprehension, but I am just learning. Thank you!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `sum(numlist)` not working?

Comment: Is the file small enough to be read into memory instead of iterating over each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not append the list but instead join the lists using `+` operator.

```
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('([0-9]+)', line)
    if len(x) > 0:
        result = map(int, x)
        numlist+=result
        #numlist.append(result) 
        print numlist

print sum(numlist)
```

**Illustration:**

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [2,3]
>>> c = [4,5]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a
[1, 2, [2, 3]]
>>> print b + c
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As you can see, `append()` appends list object at the end where as `+` joins the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
import re

line = 'the cat in the 42 hat and the cow 1772 jumps over the moon 11 11 11'
y = re.findall('([0-9]+)', line)
print sum([int(z) for z in y])
```

It does not create nested lists rather it adds all the value in a given list after converting it to integer. You can manage a temporary variable which will store the final sum and keep adding the sum of all the integers in the current line to this temporary variable.

Like this:

```
answer = 0
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('([0-9]+)', line)
    if len(x) > 0:
        answer += sum([int(z) for z in x])
print answer
```